# Why does the jq --raw-output argument fail to remove quotes from @csv output?

Tags: string, csv, jq, quotes, ffprobe

I am trying to use `jq` to reformat some elements of the JSON output generated by `ffprobe` as `csv`. I'm close (it seems to me), but struggling with a detail:

My [`ffprobe` output is shown in the jq 1.6 playground](https://jqplay.org/s/OerK1MlARS)

I'm running a recently d/l binary of jq (`jq --version` => `jq-1.6`) on MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)

From the terminal on my Mac, my results are:

```sh
$ fn_ffprobeall | jq -r '[.format.filename,.format.format_name,.format.tags.album_artist] | @csv'
"01 Jubilee.flac","flac","Bill Charlap Trio"

# where fn_ffprobeall is a function defined as: 
fn_ffprobeall () { ffprobe -i "01 Jubilee.flac" -hide_banner -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams; }
```

But this `jq` output (shown above) is not what I need... I need values *without* the surrounding quotes `""`. According to [the documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for `--raw-output / -r`:

> With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

Also, it seems odd that using `@tsv` instead of `@csv` "*does the right thing*" as the quotes will be stripped. I suppose one could do some additional work to replace `tab` chars with `,`, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something before falling back to that approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `--raw-output` option, has no control on strings passed to `@csv`, as, by that time, they are not final results of the filter. They are quoted because `@csv` quoted them.

`jq` considers the result of `@csv` as a single string output value. The `--raw-output` option works as it says in documentation, it does not encode string results in output to JSON.

If you try without that option, you will see output as `"\"01 Jubilee.flac\",\"flac\",\"Bill Charlap Trio\""`, which, is a properly encoded JSON string. It has quoting, as well as disallowed characters escaped.
You can see this difference by simply checking and unchecking the `Raw Output` option at https://jqplay.org/s/OerK1MlARS.

If you want unquoted strings in CSV, you can use `join(",")` in place of `@csv`, but it will not work well when some string itself has comma in it.

Comment: I understand your explanation - it makes sense. I wish the `jq` documentation was as clear :)  And fwiw, I was trying to add the string as a row in an existing CSV file using Excel.

Answer (score 4):

The `@csv` filter produces CSV in general accordance with the prevalent standards, which require strings to be quoted under certain circumstances (e.g. if they contain commas), and which allow fields to be quoted.

jq's -r option is much misunderstood. It only affects "top-level" JSON string outputs.  It should be used with the `@csv` option to produce CSV output, but it does not strip quotation marks from string-valued fields.

If you want to have fine-grained control over where quotation marks appear, you have numerous options (one of the simplest being `@tsv | gsub("\\t";",")`), but you then run the risk of producing invalid CSV.

Comment: OK, fair enough that the "standard" is a bit squishy. After reading your answer, I discovered [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) which adds some insights. Your answer stated, "`jq's -r option is much misunderstood. It should be...`" I may not understand what you're trying to say... I ***did*** use it with the `@csv` option, and the docs do state clearly (as i read them) that the quotes will be stripped. Can you clarify what it is that has been misunderstood?

Comment: How do you square that with the docs?: `With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes.`

Comment: Maybe that's what we've got in common: the mental block?